# exporting GPIO on Dragonboard41c using init.qcom.post_boot.sh

Tags: android, bash, gpio

I want to export the GPIO chips at boot up to allow access using Android. I have added the following to my /etc/init.qcom.post_boot.sh script:

```
set -A pins 938 915 1017 926 937 930 914 971 901 936 935
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
do
echo ${pins[i]} > /sys/class/gpio/export;
chmod 777 /sys/class/gpio/gpio${pins[i]};
chmod 777 /sys/class/gpio/gpio${pins[i]}/value;
chmod 777 /sys/class/gpio/gpio${pins[i]}/direction;
done
```

After rebooting, the export is not done. How can I export the 11 GPIO values at boot?

Comment: This *might* get more traction on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/.. depends on how popular this board is, I've never heard of it myself.

Comment: Thanks, it's the Qualcomm Snapdragon Dragonboard 410c, a development board based on the quad-core Snapdragon chip used in many cell phones. Runs on Windows IoT, Android, and Linux. It's really more of a Bash scripting question I think.

Comment: Well in bash parlance, `export` means to just set an environment var.  Is that what `pins` is in this case?  If so, environment variables don't survive reboots -- they don't even exist between different shell instances (environments).   If you run this script on boot, as soon as it's done, everything you've set will be gone.  So is an environment variable actually what you need, and if so, what in particular needs it?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, it was a syntax error, I had to delete the semicolons in the DO loop.